# mysql command not found in docker bash shell script

Tags: mysql, docker, shell

I have a shell script that copies a .sql script to a docker container and executes it.
When I execute the line:

```
docker exec -it $existingMySQLContainer bash -c '"mysql -u root -proot < setup_db.sql"'
```

on my host machine outside of the script, it works. But when I execute it from within the script, I get:

```
bash: mysql -u root -proot < setup_db.sql: command not found
```

Why doesn't this work within the script?

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# check to see if the container with the name exists.
existingMySQLContainer=$(docker ps -a -q -f name="local-test-mysql-db")
if [ ! -z "$existingMySQLContainer" ]
then
    # conatiner has been found so tear it down for a clean database
    echo "Found existing local test db " $existingMySQLContainer
    docker rm -f $existingMySQLContainer
fi

docker run --name local-test-mysql-db -d -p 3310:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql:8 


# run the docker container
existingMySQLContainer=$(docker ps -a -q -f name="local-test-mysql-db")
docker cp setup_db.sql $existingMySQLContainer:/setup_db.sql


docker exec -it $existingMySQLContainer bash -c '"mysql -u root -proot < setup_db.sql"'
```

I tried arranging the double quotes in various ways and no success.
Removing the doubles quotes to give just

Removing doubles quotes so the last line is:

```
ocker exec -it $existingMySQLContainer bash -c '"mysql -u root -proot < setup_db.sql"'
```

gives:

```
bash: mysql -u root -proot < setup_db.sql: command not found
```

SOLUTION
Docker MySQL just hadn't finished loading yet. I was trying to access it before it had finished loading.

Comment: There are too many quotes. Remove one pair.

Comment: Removing doubles quotes gives:
````
bash: mysql -u root -proot < setup_db.sql: command not found
````

Comment: Can you just use the `mysql` CLI tool from the host, connecting to a published port from your container, without doing anything Docker-specific?  Just `mysql -h127.0.0.1 <setup_db.sql`, without the `docker exec`?

Comment: Recommend instead of `docker exec` pass  `-v /path/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d' to the container startup where `/path` contains `setup_db.sql` and use `-e MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname` to create the databse [ref](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

Comment: SOLUTION
Docker MySQL just hadn't finished loading yet. I was trying to access it before it had finished loading.